Algebraically determining the domain of $\frac{x-a}{x+a}\geq0$.
I am studying Introduction to Calculus and Analysis I by Richard Courant, SECTION 1.1e, page 12, Question 2. (b) (iv).
The question is as follows: Determine the interval in which $\frac{x-a}{x+a}\geq0$ is satisfied.

My Solution
The denominator may be negative, zero, or positive, depending on whether $x$ is less than, equal to, or greater than $-a$, respectively.
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \frac{x-a}{x+a}\geq0&\iff
    \left\{\begin{aligned}
        x-a\geq0&\quad\mbox{if }x+a>0\\
        x-a\leq0&\quad\mbox{if }x+a<0
    \end{aligned}\right.\\
    &\iff
    \left\{\begin{aligned}
        x\geq a&\quad\mbox{if }x>-a\\
        x\leq a&\quad\mbox{if }x<-a
    \end{aligned}\right.\\
    &\iff(x\geq a\land x>-a)\lor(x\leq a\land x<-a)
\end{aligned}
$$
This seems to leave me with the interval $x\in(-\infty,-a)\cup(a,\infty)$. This agrees with graphical evidence: [note that the root occurs when $x=a$.]


My Question
I believe that my answer is correct and that this is true for all $a\neq0$. However, I am concerned about my usage of the logical and. It seems that, for instance, $x\geq a$ follows from $x>-a$ (they aren't simultaneously ture, one follows from the other). While it is true that the domain is only concerned with situations where both are satisfied, I am not certain that
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
        x\geq a&\quad\mbox{if }x>-a\\
        x\leq a&\quad\mbox{if }x<-a
    \end{aligned}\right.
$$
is logically equivalent to
$$
(x\geq a\land x>-a)\lor(x\leq a\land x<-a)
$$
I seek either a justification of this "if and only if" which I have called into question, or the way I should have done it properly if it is incorrect. It seems in the one case, we have things in "this implies that" statements, whereas in the other, they are in "these are simultaneously true" statements.
As noted in the comments, this seems to imply that it is okay to do
$$
(a\implies b\lor c\implies d)\iff(a\land b)\lor(c\land d)
$$
in this case. If it is, why is that so?


Yes, it looks good.

@Theincredibleidiot It seems to say $(a\implies b\lor c\implies d)\iff(a\land b)\lor(c\land d)$. I like the confidence, but I'm still looking for justification of this in this instance. Why is it correct?

I am wondering how I could account for when $b$ or $d$ may be true, and $a$ or $c$ false in my attempt at an equivalence: $(a\implies b\lor c\implies d)\iff(a\land b)\lor(c\land d)$
